# How can I solve this partitions question?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $p_n$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ in which no part occurs more than twice and let $q_n$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ in which no part is divisible by $3$. Show that $p_n=q_n$, $n≥0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_1(n)$ be the set of partitions of $n$ that have a part that occurs more than twice but do **not** have a part that is a multiple of $3$. Let $P_2(n)$ be the set of partitions of $n$ that do not have a part that occurs more than twice but **do** have a part that is a multiple of $3$. Finally, let $P_3(n)$ be the set of partitions of $n$ that do not have a part that occurs more than twice and do not have a part that is a multiple of $3$. You want to show that $|P_1(n)\cup P_3(n)|=|P_2(n)\cup P_3(n)|$, and because the sets $P_1(n),P_2(n)$, and $P_3(n)$ are pairwise disjoint, this is true if and only if $|P_1(n)|=|P_2(n)|$. Thus, you can prove the result by showing that there is a bijection between $P_1(n)$ and $P_2(n)$.

HINT: There is a very easy way to convert a part that is a multiple of $3$ into a part that occurs more than twice and *vice versa*.

Answer (score 0):

No part used more than twice ... $(1+x^n+x^{2n})$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+x^n+x^{2n})
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply top & bottom by $(1-x^n)$ ... cancel $(1-x^{3n})$ ...